# Ffmpeg and OpenCv versions incompatibility

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

I installed Python 2.7.5 and OpenCV 2.4. I'm trying to follow the instructions of this page 
http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html
And it suggest to install the proper version of Ffmpeg. I installed it following the instructions of this page 
http://adaptivesamples.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/
Which tells the user how to add Ffmpeg to the environment variables.
However, the sample code doesn't work. And I don't know if it is because the versions of OpenCv and ffmpeg are incompatible with one another. 
I'll leave the sample code here.
Thanks for reading :D

```
import numpy as np import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vtest.avi')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release() cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: what is the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: It just doesn't work.